# Merge Sort using recursion

Tags: java, sorting, recursion

I tried to implement a recursive merge-sort, but I get a stack overflow error.

```
public class MergeSort {
    static int input[],mid;
    public static void mergeSort(int input[],int start,int end ){
        if(start>end){
            return;
        }
// dividing input array into two equal parts
        mid=(start+end)/2;
        mergeSort(input,start,mid);
        mergeSort(input,mid+1,end);
        merge(input,start,mid,end);
    }
    public static void merge(int input[],int start,int mid,int end )
    {
        int l[]=new int[mid-start+1];
        int r[]=new int[end-mid];
        for(int i=1;i<end-start+1;i++){
            l[i]=input[start+i-1];
        }
        for(int j=1;j<end-mid;j++){
            r[j]=input[mid+j];
        }

    l[end-start+2]='\u221e';// ASCII vlaue of infinity at the end of left array
    r[end-mid+1]='\u221e';//ASCII vlaue of infinity at the end of right array
    int i=1,j=1;
    for(int k=start;k<end;k++){
        if(l[i]<=r[j]){
            input[k]=l[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else{
            input[k]=r[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you understand what StackOverflow means, that should hint you where the problem lies.

Comment: How big is the interval you are testing? Do you even have a **StackOverflow** on small inputs? If no, is the resulting output even correct? If it also happens on small inputs than you probably have an error on your recursion strategy. Try checking if you call the method on the correct indices and also if your stop criterion is correct. **StackOverflow** indicates that your recursion either will not halt or is just too big to compute (e.g. out of memory). Check the code against pseudo-code from Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: Where is the trace from your debugging efforts?  If nothing else, stick a trivial `print` command at the top of each method to display the input arguments.  That much will tell you a lot about the recursion progression.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your termination condition:

```
    if(start > end){
        return;
    }
    // dividing input array into two equal parts
    mid=(start+end)/2;
    mergeSort(input,start,mid);   //  <= infinite recursion
    mergeSort(input,mid+1,end);
```

In the first recursion, there is no way to reduce `mid` (the next `end` value) to be *less* than `start`.  For instance, starting with the range [0, 6], here is the sequence of `start, end` values for the first recursive call:

```
0 6    mid = (0+6)/2 = 3
0 3    mid = (0+3)/2 = 1
0 1    mid = (0+1)/2 = 0
0 0    mid = (0+0)/2 = 0
0 0    mid = (0+0)/2 = 0
...
```

You never get to a point where `start > end`.  Infinite recursion.

Perhaps `start >= end` would work for you?  That makes your base case a 1-item array, rather than an empty array.

Comment: Nice explanation of why this is infinite recursion (better than mine I think), I'll upvote once I get more votes.

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite recursion. Look at the calls carefully:

```
if(start>end){
        return;
    }
 // dividing input array into two equal parts
    mid=(start+end)/2;
    mergeSort(input,start,mid);
    mergeSort(input,mid+1,end);
    merge(input,start,mid,end);
```

You're always passing the same value of `start` for the first call - you never actually change it - and `mid` can never be less than `start`. Thus, your terminating condition can never hold and this is infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't think that's correct: the code *does* change `start` in the 2nd call and changes `end` in the 1st.  Note that `merge` is *not* recursive.  This is the basic merge-sort principle: sort each half individually; then merge the results.

Comment: @Prune But for the first call (`mergeSort(input, start, mid)`) *is*, in fact, infinite because there's no way for `start > end` to be true.

Comment: @Prune Looking at this again I probably could've phrased it more clearly, I'll edit.